# Make preg_match_all stop capturing at newline?

Tags: php, regex

Consider this example, where I try to obtain the "raw" e-mail addresses:

```
<?php
$tststr = 'To: user1@example1.com
To: user2@example2.com, anotheruser3@example3.com
To: User <user4@example4.com>
To: User <user5@example5.com>, Another User <anotheruser6@example6.com>
';

//~ preg_match('/([^ <]*@[^ >,]*)/', $tststr, $matches); // no /g
preg_match_all('/([^ <]*@[^ >,$]*)/m', $tststr, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $key=>$val) {
  //~ print("val [".$key."] = ". $val . "\n");
  foreach ($val as $key1=>$val1) {
    print("val [".$key."][".$key1."] = ". $val1 . "\n");
  }
}

print "'".$matches[0][0]."'\n";
?>
```

I'm thinking the regex works like this:

- `[^ <]*` - select sequence of chars which are not (`^`) space or angle bracket `<`
- `@` - select `@` char
- `[^ >,$]*` - select sequence of chars which are not (`^`) space, angle bracket `<`, comma `,` or end-of-line `$`
- `/m` apparently [makes `^` and `$` match start/end of lines in addition to start/end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499127/preg-match-all-and-newlines-inside-quotes/2499165#2499165)

And mostly it works, as the result is:

```
val [0][0] = user1@example1.com
To:
val [0][1] = user2@example2.com
val [0][2] = anotheruser3@example3.com
To:
val [0][3] = user4@example4.com
val [0][4] = user5@example5.com
val [0][5] = anotheruser6@example6.com
val [1][0] = user1@example1.com
To:
val [1][1] = user2@example2.com
val [1][2] = anotheruser3@example3.com
To:
val [1][3] = user4@example4.com
val [1][4] = user5@example5.com
val [1][5] = anotheruser6@example6.com
'user1@example1.com
To:'
```

... except, as you can see, the match [0][0] actually contains the newline, and the '`To:`' from the next line!

So, how can I have the `preg_match_all` stop captures at end of line?

Subquestion: why do I have to identical set of results in `$matches[0]` and `$matches[1]`? Can I ignore `$matches[1]`, and just go about processing `$matches[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace space present inside the character class with `\s` . Hence this won't match any space character including line breaks.

```
preg_match_all('/([^\s<]*@[^\s>,$]*)/m', $tststr, $matches);
```

This can be further simplified as below, ie, you don't need to use capturing group and multiline modifier `m`

```
preg_match_all('/[^\s<]*@[^\s>,$]*/', $tststr, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eJ0aN4/1)

`$` inside a char class will match a literal `$` symbol. Not , it takes like not of end of the line. WE don't need to include `\n` inside the negated char class, since `\s`  does the job.

```
preg_match_all('/[^\s<]*@[^\s>,]*/', $tststr, $matches);
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @AvinashRaj - that works; and removing the capture group parentheses also removes the `$matches[1]` set. I also think the `$` in the `[^\s>,$]*` is not needed anymore, as I thought it would be a symbol to match a newline. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: you don't mean a literal `$`? then remove it from the character class. `$` inside a char class will loose it's meaning (matching end of the line boundary)